# Why is the attribute target 'typevar' undocumented?

Tags: c#, attributes

As is well known, in C# one can specify the *target* of a custom attribute specification, as in the example

```
[method: SomeDecoration]
[return: SomeOtherMark]
int MyMethod();
```

where the "targets" `method:` and `return:` help specify what element in the code the attribute belongs to.

According to the C# Language Specification, the following attribute targets exist:

- Global ones:

  - `assembly`
  - `module`
- Others:

  - `field`
  - `event`
  - `method`
  - `param`
  - `property`
  - `return`
  - `type`

Some of them, like `field`, are *always* redundant, since it is always clear what the attribute "sits" on without specifying them.

However there does exist (at least in the implementation and version of Visual C# I have here) an additional attribute target, namely:

- `typevar`

which is allowed for example in the code

```
class MyGenericCollection<[typevar: HereYouSee] TItem>    // legal
{
}
```

The attribute target `typevar`, just like `field` and others, is never required.

*My question:* Does anyone know the historic reason why `typevar:` is not mentioned in the specification or documentation? Was this simply forgotten when the 2.0 version of the C# Language Specification was written? Or if it was not an oversight, why is it implemented at all?

Comment: My guess (but it's nothing more than a guess) is that it wasn't documented because it's useless: there is no possible ambiguity about what the attribute is applied to, so specifying `typevar` never changes the meaning of the code.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I thought about that as well, but as far as I can see, `type:` and certainly `property:` are "useless" too in the exact same sense, and still they *are* documented.

Comment: Three people think this thread should be closed because it is too "opinion-based"? However, I try to ask neutrally; I am not asking, "do you guys think the spec or implementation is good or bad", I am asking, "does anyone know factually the story about `typevar:`".

Comment: Don't worry about the close votes... Some people see that someone voted to close and just do the same without thinking. If the question is closed, it will be reopened in no time.

Comment: I would not agree with statement that some "targets" are useless. They are very helpful in case when you want to limit your custom attribute usage, and do not want if someone put your attribute on somewhat undesirable.

Comment: Looking at [`AttributeTargets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx) it seems to be a much un-loved target - it's not supported by VB or C++, only C#. So maybe it's floating somewhere in the realms of "we added it but don't really want anyone to use it"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever maybe, but looking ms sources, they were very conservative in the beginning.

Comment: @ValBakhtin I think you misunderstand "useless" here (it was a bad word to use). The members of the `AttributeTargets` enum are not exactly the same as the C# code elements. For example using `AttributeTargets.Property` ***is*** useful for limiting where an attribute type can be put. But saying, in C#, `[property: Something] public int P { get; set; }` is exactly the same as `[Something] public int P { get; set; }`, so `property:` is in a sense never necessary. Also, `AttributeTagets.GenericParameter` is well-documented, while `typevar:` is not specified in official C# specs.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen, yes, I did misunderstand you, I was thinking about AttributeTargets enum. Sorry.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque It seems your prediction was wrong. (I found this question just now, and voted to reopen.)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `typevar` attribute target is documented, but it seems that only in the standardized C# 2.0 Language Specification:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf#page=399

Neither C# [3.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), nor [5.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.docx) Language Specification mentions `typevar`. (I didn't find C# 4.0 spec.)

So answering your second question, no, it wasn't forgotten in C# 2.0, but it is forgotten since then :) I think this must be an oversight, since the `typevar` attribute target is still (C# 5.0) valid.

Comment: Very good find. When .NET 2.0 and C# 2 came from Microsoft, as far as I remember, the *Word* format C# Language Specification did not contain everything in C# but only the stuff that was new or changed in version 2. See [this file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/f/98fdf0c7-2bbd-40d3-9fd1-5a4159fa8044/csharp%202.0%20specification_sept_2005.doc).