# Finding Contextual Keywords with Roslyn

Tags: c#, keyword, var, roslyn

I'm having some difficulty identifying contextual keywords (var, yield, async etc.) with Roslyn. I've inherited from [`CSharpSyntaxWalker`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxWalker.cs#ec6c624452896e8b) and overrode `VisitToken`. `SyntaxToken` exposes an extension method [`IsContextualKeyword()`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpExtensions.cs#6475b21b0ea3d4b2) but it always returns false.

Here's a sample that should output all contextual keywords in a syntax tree:

```
public class TokenWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public TokenWalker() : base(SyntaxWalkerDepth.Token) { }

    public override void VisitToken(SyntaxToken token)
    {
        //Trying to determine if we're visiting a contextual keyword
        if (token.IsContextualKeyword())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
        }
        base.VisitToken(token);
    }
}
```

And using this class as follows:

```
public static void TaggingVarKeyword()
{
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            var var = 4;
        }
    }
    ");

    var walker = new TokenWalker();
    walker.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
}
```

I'd expect an output of 'var', but I get no output at all.

If I place a breakpoint at `VisitToken()` I see that var is passed in as an `IdentifierToken` not a `TypeVarKeyword`.

Is it possible to determine contextual keywords at a purely syntactical level? If so, do you know how I could go about doing this?

Comment: You cannot know that `var` is a contextual keyword without semantic information (in case of `class var { }`).  That is not true for all contextual keyword (especially `get` & `set`)

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose SyntaxKind.TypeVarKeyword is present only for the sake of completion then. I can't imagine a situation in which it would be used.

Comment: In fact, it maps back to the non-keyword text "typevar": http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxKindFacts.cs#1529

Comment: @JoshVarty Actually, that's the undocumented/badly documented [`typevar` attribute target](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20888126/41071) (which I had no idea existed until now).