# C# Roslyn Compiler Syntaxkind Value Keyword

Tags: c#, roslyn

i am currently using the Syntax API from Roslyn to generate some C# code and i am wondering about a small thing when defining a set accessor like this:

```
var setAccessor = AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration)
.AddBodyStatements(ExpressionStatement(InvocationExpression(IdentifierName("SetField"))
.AddArgumentListArguments(Argument(IdentifierName("value")))));
var propertyDeclaration = PropertyDeclaration(ParseTypeName("FieldType"), "Field")
                .AddModifiers(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                .AddAccessorListAccessors(setAccessor);
```

which works perfectly fine. I am just a bit confused about the `value` keyword in the setAccessor, because normally i would expect to be able to declare it like this:

```
IdentifierName(Token(SyntaxKind.ValueKeyWord))
```

but as far as I can see there is no `SyntaxKind.ValueKeyword`, am I missing something or do I get something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[`value` is a special contextual keyword.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value)

> The contextual keyword `value` is used in the `set` accessor in property and indexer declarations. It is similar to an input parameter of a method.

The C# standard spec says:

> The following identifiers have special meaning in the syntactic grammar, but they are not keywords: add (§17.7), alias (§16.3), get (§17.6.2), global (§16.7), partial (§17.1.4), remove (§17.7), set (§17.6.2), value (§17.6.2, §17.7.2), where (§25.7), and yield (§15.14). For convenience and clarity, these identifiers appear as terminals in the syntactic grammar; however, they are identifiers. [Note: As a result, unlike keywords, these identifiers can be written with a @ prefix and can contain unicode-escape-sequences. end note]

In other words, the syntax model treats all contextual keywords as identifiers, rather than as regular keywords. Some contextual keywords (like `yield`) do appear in [SyntaxKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxkind), but others (like `var` and `value` do not).

[This github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4861) includes some relevant discussion, including this:

> it is a *contextual keyword*, but not a *keyword*. Roslyn's syntactic model only contains explicit support for contextual keywords for which the context is syntactic. That is why the syntactic model doesn't tell you about the contextual keywords `var` and `value`. In any case all of the contextual keywords are identifiers.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24592111/120955) is related.

Comment: Ok thx, but I see this `SyntaxKind.VarKeyword` and also `add` , `alias`, `get`, `global`, `partial`, `remove`, `set`, `where` and `yield` have SyntaxKind entries. So to me it seems the only one missing in `value` or not?